# MS-Access 2003 trigger an append query from a command button click

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2003

I have an append query that I would like to trigger off of a command button click.  I have my splash screen with a command button that executes a Close & Open command.  I want to combind the append query to execute during this click event.

My VBA for the splash screen

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub SplCls_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_SplCls_Click

DoCmd.Close

stDocName = "Switchboard"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName

Exit_SplCls_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_SplCls_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_SplCls_Click

End Sub
```

I know enoug to know it needs to go in between the DoCmd.Close & DoCmd.OpenForm.  The Append query is named "qry_YOS"  Any guidance on this segment of code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DAO Database `Excute` method to run your append query.  If you want that to happen between `.Close` and `.OpenForm` ...

```
DoCmd.Close ' close what?  If it works, fine.  '
CurrentDb.Execute "qry_YOS", dbFailonerror
stDocName = "Switchboard"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
```

BTW, always include `Option Explict` in the Declarations of your code modules like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
```

From the VB Editor's main menu, select Tools->Options.  Then on the Editor tab of the Options dialog, place a check mark next to "Require Variable Declaration".  That setting will ensure `Option Explict` is included in all *new* code modules.  I strongly recommend you manually add it to any of your existing code modules which don't already have it.  Then choose Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu and fix anything the compiler complains about.  Hopefully that won't be too much, but in the long run it's a good investment.

Life as a VBA developer without `Option Explicit` is unnecessarily complicated.  Just always use it to save yourself grief.  You can thank me later.  :-)

Comment: Thanks HansUp!  I appreciate your guidance!